# Add a non changing third line in power BI line chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, linechart

I am creating a line chart in power BI using the following sample data.

| year-mo | location | status | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01 | Antioch | applied | 1,235 |
| 2022-01 | Central Valley | applied | 1,545 |
| 2022-01 | Diablo | in prog | 2,154 |
| 2022-01 | East Bay | applied | 525 |
| 2022-01 | Fremont | in prog | 215,464 |
| 2022-01 | Fresno | applied | 121,654 |
| 2022-01 | Golden Gate | in prog | 214 |
| 2022-01 | Greater SF | applied | 12,464 |
| 2022-01 | Greater SA | applied | 12,165 |
| 2022-01 | Manteca | in prog | 1,454 |
| 2022-01 | TOTAL | statALL | 526 |
| 2022-01 | TOTAL excl | exempt | 653 |
| 2022-02 | Antioch | applied | 2,565 |
| 2022-02 | Central Valley | applied | 123 |
| 2022-02 | Diablo | in prog | 452 |
| 2022-02 | East Bay | applied | 154 |
| 2022-02 | Fremont | in prog | 33,244 |
| 2022-02 | Fresno | applied | 21 |
| 2022-02 | Golden Gate | applied | 214 |
| 2022-02 | Greater SF | in prog | 6,542 |
| 2022-02 | Greater SA | applied | 224 |
| 2022-02 | Manteca | in prog | 248 |
| 2022-02 | TOTAL | statALL | 852 |
| 2022-02 | TOTAL excl | exempt | 5,789 |

The data has four columns: date, location, status, and amount.

the location has values like 'TOTAL', 'Sacramento', 'Golden Gate'. status has 'applied','in prog','statALL', 'exempt'.

I would like to create a line chart responsive to the selected filter values, which is easy to make. The caveat is I also need to show the statALL line to always appear no matter what the value of the filter was chosen. It is like comparing the lines of Manteca applied, menteca in prog, and those two lines are compared with statALL line. Same with when a different location is chosen. I would admit I tried chatg, claude, and bard, but nothing seemed to work. Bard was not able to provide a possible solution.

The location is the filter. The status is the legend. The line chart will have three lines in it, comparing the lines of each location and their corresponding status, against the statALL (product) line which will always show when choosing a location.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your data table. You say it has 4 columns but you only show 3 in the sample. Is "TOTAL" a pre-calculated metric/value and not actually the total for that month? It is unusual to see "TOTAL" in a data row. Please help describe what the "TOTAL" row is. Which filter or filters will you be using for the chart? And if two or more locations are selected, do you want to see each one with a separate line or one line with them sum'd together?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing two solutions for you depending on your need.

1. Simple solution but will only show two lines, one for the sum of the locations filtered, and one for the TOTAL.
2. More complex solution but this one will show each filtered location and TOTAL as separate lines.

---

**Solution 1 (simple)**

Create a new Measure with:

```
TOTAL =
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(YourTable[amount]),
    REMOVEFILTERS(YourTable[location]),
    YourTable[location] = "TOTAL"
  )
```

Then in your chart, add `YourTable[amount]` and `[TOTAL]` into the Y-axis.

---

**Solution 2 (more complex)**

Solution 2 requires a separate table for the location values, and we'll use this for the Legend of the chart.

Create a Calculated Table (or do the equivalent in PowerQuery):

```
Dim Location = DISTINCT(YourTable[location])
```

Add a new Measure with:

```
Amount with TOTAL = 
  var thisLocation = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim Location'[location])

  return SWITCH(TRUE(),
    thisLocation = "TOTAL",
      CALCULATE(SUM(YourTable[sum of amount]), YourTable[location] = "TOTAL"),

    thisLocation IN VALUES('YourTable'[location]), 
      CALCULATE(SUM('YourTable'[sum of amount]), YourTable[location] = thisLocation)
  )
```

Now for your chart, add `[Amount with TOTAL]` to the Y-axis, and add `'Dim Location'[location]` to the Legend.

---

**Results**

[image]

- The slicer is using `'YourTable'[location]` for both visuals.
- Note how Solution 1 is show the sum of the two locations selected, whereas Solution 2 shows a line for each.

Comment: sorry about the confusion in the description. I intend to have separate lines just like your solution 2.  I will try and let you know

Comment: I guess the missing fourth column is necessary. The location is in the filter, but the legend will be the product, assuming we have product1, product2 and product 3. There will be lines for product1 and prdduct2. If a user will choose Diablo, the charts will show separate lines for Diabloproduct1 and Diabloproduct2, then the third line will be TOTALproduct3.  If users filter to Fremont, the lines will be Fremontproduct1, Fremontproduct2, then TOTALproduct3. TOTALproduct3 will always show no matter what the location filter is.

Comment: also how are you able to connect the dim Location table with the main data table by date?

Comment: Please update your question with the proper data table with all the columns.

Comment: updated the question and the table